# Check if view is animating

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an extension function to make any view do "scale animation" when clicked, but this function doesn't check if the view is animating. Because of this, when the user clicks many times (and the view has not finished the animation) the view scales and increases the view's original size...

I need to prevent this. Maybe checking if the view is animating and animate only when the view is not animating

```
fun View.setOnClickWithScaleAnimListener(block: View.() -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener { v ->
        v.animate()
            .scaleXBy(0.1f)
            .scaleYBy(0.1f)
            .setDuration(80)
            .withEndAction {
                v.animate()
                    .scaleXBy(-0.1f)
                    .scaleYBy(-0.1f)
                    .duration = 80
            }

        block(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cheticamp for give me an idea.
Just set `isClickable` is not enough, because if the user click many times fast, the view continues to increase.
I solved just replacing `scaleXBy` for `scaleX/scaleY`, `scaleX/scaleY` set the `X/Y` to a `X/Y` value and `scaleXBy/scaleYBy` increase the `X/Y` by a specific value.

```
fun View.setOnClickWithScaleAnimListener(block: View.() -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener { v ->
        v.animate()
            .scaleX(1.1f)
            .scaleY(1.1f)
            .setDuration(80)
            .withEndAction {
                v.animate()
                    .scaleX(1f)
                    .scaleY(1f)
                    .duration = 80
                isClickable = true

            }
            .withStartAction {
                isClickable = false
            }

        block(this)
    }
}
```

set `isClickable` is not required, but if you need to prevent user "cancel" the scale animation, then is required to set `isClickable`

Answer (score 5):

When the view is clicked, disable its "click-ability" before the animation starts. At the end of all animations, restore the ability to click the view. This, in essence, disables the listener during animation without having to remove it.

```
fun View.setOnClickWithScaleAnimListener(block: View.() -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener { v ->
        v.animate()
            .scaleXBy(0.1f)
            .scaleYBy(0.1f)
            .setDuration(80)
            .withStartAction { v.isClickable = false }
            .withEndAction {
                v.animate()
                    .scaleXBy(-0.1f)
                    .scaleYBy(-0.1f)
                    .setDuration(80)
                    .withEndAction { v.isClickable = true }
            }
        block(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cancel the current animation. It's a no-op if no animation is in progress:

```
fun View.setOnClickWithScaleAnimListener(block: View.() -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener { v ->
        v.animate().cancel()
        v.animate()
            .scaleXBy(0.1f)
            .scaleYBy(0.1f)
            .setDuration(80)
            .withEndAction {
                v.animate()
                    .scaleXBy(-0.1f)
                    .scaleYBy(-0.1f)
                    .duration = 80
            }

        block(this)
    }
}
```

Edit: you can disable the view during the animation, would that solve you problem?

```
this.setOnClickListener { v ->
    v.isEnabled = false
    v.animate()
            .scaleXBy(0.1f)
            .scaleYBy(0.1f)
            .setDuration(80)
            .withEndAction {
                v.animate()
                        .scaleXBy(-0.1f)
                        .scaleYBy(-0.1f)
                        .setDuration(80)
                        .withEndAction { v.isEnabled = true }
            }

    block(this)
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I think the problem is not cancel the animation, the problem is that when the view are clicked, first step is increase X and Y (scale) and the last step is decrease... If I click 2 times the view increase 2 times, because with this animation code, the view scale X and Y by 0,1f of the current size

Comment: I can't disable, becase some view (like button) have disable/enable layout